# MongoDB ubunto error, exiting with code 1

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, ubuntu, nosql

i am a front stack dev trying to become full stack, been learning node and express and wanted to start with mongo, i went to the officlal mongodb page and followed the instruction to download mongo trough the cli in ubuntu 20.4
finished with the commands, i typed mongo in the command line and get this in mi cli

`MongoDB shell version v4.4.4 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17 @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed exiting with code 1`

what is that? im new at this side of coding and feel a bit overwelm by this, i appreciate the help you would give me

Comment: You may have installed mongo - did you also start it?

Comment: with sudo systemctl start mongod you mean? if so, yes i did.

Comment: Is it running? What port  is it listening on?  `sudo netstat -anp | grep mongo`

Answer (score 0):

i had a similiar issue this probably happened because you failed to start mongodb service before opening the mongo shell.
next time run the command
`sudo systemctl start mongod`
this helps to start the mongodb service
to check if the service is running successfully you can then run the command
`sudo systemctl status mongod`
after which you can proceed to run the command
`mongo`
to run the mongo shell. this hack only applies to ubuntu system.